# как подсчитать количество уникальных слов в тексте? php

Tags: php

Подскажите, как подсчитать количество уникальных слов в тексте?
     Данная функция подсчитывает все слова в тексте:

```
 count($rows);
```

Comment: смотря что у вас в `$rows`. если ключ => значение (слово) - то через http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php  ........ если там целые строки, то по-другому. нужно больше информации

Comment: там текст, полученный из формы (input). Ключа нет

Comment: если текст из input, то `count` ну никак не может считать количество слов. Нужно больше информации, что у вас имеется, что куда передается. .......если с Input слова через пробел разделены, то в начале применить  `explode`, `trim` и потом `array_unique`,  `count`

Comment: $rows = explode(" ", $a);

       //подсчитала слова (уникальные)
       echo count(array_unique($rows)).'<br>';            Еще последний пробел считает за слово

Comment: *как подсчитать* — 1. разбить на слова, 2. отсортировать, 3. удалить дубликаты, 4. подсчитать оставшиеся слова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `$rows` это строка:

```
$rows = "Hello frind, you're
       looking   looking     looking  good today!";
$couns_words = str_word_count($rows, 1);

$unique_array = array_count_values($couns_words);
print_r($unique_array);

$count_unique = count($unique_array);
print_r($count_unique);

//или

$count_unique = count(array_unique($couns_words));
print_r($count_unique);
```

Или что то вроде:

```
$couns_words = preg_split('/\s+/',$rows);
$count_unique = count(array_unique($couns_words));
print_r($count_unique);
```